# Can I use different length of input data in neural networks?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I would like to encode my input letters of strings for machine learning methods. At the moment my train data looks in this way:

```
  score     text
    1   show photos
    1   show photos
    2   who are you
```

As you can see all texts have the same length. At the bottom is my source code. I wonder whether it is possible to use different length of vectors? For instance:

```
  score     text
    1   show my photos
    1   show me my photos
    2   can you tell me who are you?
```

Source code:

```
train_set = pd.read_csv("train3.tsv", sep="\t", header = None, names=['score', 'text'], skip_blank_lines=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, error_bad_lines=False)
test_set = pd.read_csv("test.tsv", sep="\t", header = None, names=['text'], skip_blank_lines=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, error_bad_lines=False)

dictionary = {}
i=0

for index, row in train_set.iterrows():

    list2 = list(row.text.lower())

    for n, key in enumerate(list2):

        if key in dictionary:

            list2[n] = dictionary[key]

        else:

            dictionary[key] = i
            list2[n] = i
            i += 1

    train_set.set_value(index,'text', list2)


for index, row in test_set.iterrows():

    list2 = list(row.text.lower())

    for n, key in enumerate(list2):

        if key in dictionary:

            list2[n] = dictionary[key]

        else:

            dictionary[key] = i
            list2[n] = i
            i += 1

    test_set.set_value(index,'text', list2)

# Create first network with Keras

score = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in train_set.score.values.tolist()])

text = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in train_set.text.values.tolist()])

test = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in test_set.text.values.tolist()])

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=11, init='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(11, init='uniform'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(text, score, epochs=150, batch_size=10,  verbose=2)
# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(test)
print(predictions)
```

Comment: NO, you can't use different length for input , but if you use word vectors you can for example use average of them , or use an embedding layer with one-hot vectors.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ Yes, but I would rather not to use bag of words and it seems to me that one-hot vectors based on it. I would like to save the location of each letter in sentence. Do you think that encoding string as in given example `show photos` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 0]` is an acceptable solution? And for instance to encode `show phot` I would use something like this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, -1, -1]` I will be added `-1` to have the same length of all strings. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what result will you get, but the padding approach always have its cons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have different lengths; however, you need a layer that can handle varying lengths. For example, you can use an LSTM to process the sentences of varying lengths by setting `input_shape=(None, vocab_size)` where `None` indicates an unknown number of words.

You still need to *pad* the sequences to same length, using `pad_sequences` in utils. Then you need to use a `Masking` layer to tell the LSTM that those entries are to be skipped. If you just set to -1 and not mask then you'll introduce bias based on the length of sentences in the training set.

Comment: Do you think that your solution will be more efficient than encoding string as in given example `show photos` to defined size of array for instance like this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]` where -1 will be added to have the same length of all strings or maybeI should stay with this solution?

Comment: You shouldn't pad with -1 and actually use the values, you will just introduce bias, your model will learn whether the sentence is padded or not. For example, if class 2 is always longer than examples in class 1 then the model will classify based on that rather than the words. But yes, it will be slower than a Dense layer as it is recurrent.

Comment: Do you have an example or can you show me how it can be done?

Comment: There are many recurrent examples, have a look at IMDb [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py).

Answer (score -1):

Your input has to have the same size all the time. So what you can do, is to insert a value at the end of smaller inputs (let's say -1). Then the neural network will figure it out and deals with it.

Comment: Do you think that encoding string as in given example `show photos` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 2, 0]` is an acceptable solution? I guess that you mean that I should encode for instance `show phot` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, -1, -1]`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just consider that changing characters to numbers is not that efficient. Instead, I would suggest converting each word to numeric data. You can implement this your self, but if your input can be very different, use a nltk, which can be used to get a list of identical numbers for each word

Comment: I would like to work on letters. Can you recommend any method that will help me create vectors with values `-1` to have the same length in all sentences? My problem is that I am not sure what will be the max length of sentence. So let's assume that I will train it using array of 50 encoded numbers (sentence will contain 50 letters or less) and then my model will get a sentence consisting of 60 characters and it will be the problem. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Please consider, by using letters it's also impossible to get a good result. A rule of thumb for getting the features is that can a human find the answer by seeing the features? If you use letters it will be very difficult for your network to find the relations. Also, about the problem, you have to set some sort of limit for the input.